# How to use resumable upload feature of pandastream

Tags: ios, objective-c, pandastream

I am creating an app which requires resumable video upload. I intend to upload videos to pandastream.

I already went to http://www.pandastream.com/docs/upload_api

I started from creating upload session.

```
    ->
    POST /videos/upload.json
    Host: api.pandastream.com
    --
    file_size     :     integer
    file_name     :     string

    <-
    Status Code 201

   "id"          :     integer
   "location"    :     location to upload the video
```

How do I send this request in objective-C. Please give a detailed answer and forgive my lack of knowledge.

Comment: Hey, you need to Authenticate the query first. And get a token to hash then send back with the query to POST the video. I'll do a version over the next two days and answer your question.

Comment: Actually I just realised, you will still need a server side page to handle the panda notifications of when the video is encoded and then complete. Maybe the best way would be to send your video from your app to a web service that does the panda upload, authentication and handles the returned notifications?